# How to ingest data effectively in Neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j, data-modeling

I  am looking for advice on the best way to handle data going into Neo4j.

I have a set of structured data, CSV format which relates to journeys. The data is:

**"JourneyID"**   - unique ref#/ Primary Key e.g 1234

**"StartID"**  - ref#  , this is a station e.g Station1

**"EndIID"** - ref# this is a station, e.g Station1 (start and end can be the same)

**"Time"** – integer e.g. 24

Assume I have 100 journeys/rows of data, showing journeys between 10 different stations.

I can see and work with this data in SQL or Excel. I want to work with this in Neo4j.

This is what I currently have:

StartID with JourneyID as a label
EndID with Journey ID as a label

This means that each row from the CSV for a station is its own node. I then created a relationship between Start and End using the JourneyID (primary key) 
 the effect was just  100 node connected to 100 nodes. E.g connection from Station1 and Station 2, Station 1 and Station 3, and Station 1 and Station 4. It didn’t show the relationship between Starting Station1 and Ending Station1, 2 and 3 - which is what I want to show.

How best do I model this data so that graph sees 10 unique StartID, connecting to the different EndIDs – showing the relationships between them?

Thanks in advance

(new to Graphs!)

Comment: Can you show your actual Cypher query in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you want a Journey to be a node, you want the Journey ID to be an attribute of the edge:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file://input.csv' AS row
MERGE (start:Station {id: row.StartID})
MERGE (end:Station {id: row.EndID})
MERGE (start)-[:JOURNEY {id:row.JourneyID}]->(end)
```

That more intuitively describes the data, and you could even extend this to different relationship types, if you can describe Journeys in more detail.

#### Edit:

This is to answer your question, but I can't speak as to how this scales up. I think it depends on the types of queries you plan to make.

Comment: Thank you for this -  this gives me visually exactly what I needed and (I hope!) gives me the data to work with for the next phase. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

This sample query, which uses [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/) to avoid creating duplicate nodes and relationships, should help you get started:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file://input.csv' AS row
MERGE (start:Station {id: row.StartID})
MERGE (end:Station {id: row.EndID})
MERGE (j:Journey {id: row.JourneyID})
ON CREATE SET j.time = row.Time
MERGE (j)-[:FROM]->(start)
MERGE (j)-[:TO]->(end)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a big improvement but does not quite solve the problem.
 I now see the relationships between the journey and station, but not between the station and station. 
I.e I can see that Station X had Journey 1 and 2 and that Journey 1 connected to Station X and Station Y and Journey 2 was to from Station X to Station Z
I would like to be able to do is see that X was connected to Station Y and Z (directly).  This will then allow me to see the relationships directly.

Comment: No, you should NOT add redundant relationships, as it is really complex to keep all the associated relationships (indirect and direct) consistent (especially if there are concurrent requests), and you'd end up with many more relationships as well. You should just rely on the quick relationship traversals offered by a graph DB like neo4j.

Comment: Thanks for coming back - I am just hanging in there on my understanding!. When I "see" the data following the above code the information I "see" when its shown does appear to be redundant to me - which is what I wanted to avoid.  However, when I follow the code in the response from sjc in the other post I just get the station to station relationships.  If you have a moment, and I am conscious of asking for yet more time...could you comment/explain a little more on the benefits of this method rather than the other one presented? Either thank you so much for giving the detail so far.

Comment: The other answer does not have `Journey` nodes, which is fine if you will never want to find a specific Journey (by `id`). But if you do want to do that, then it would be more performant to have Journey nodes, since you can create normal [indexes](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/administration/indexes-for-search-performance/) for nodes but not relationships. You should pick one approach or the other, but not try to combine them.

Comment: Thanks again - really helpful